# Overriding virtual methods separately in multiple inheritance layout

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Is there a way to override separately functions with same names (from two parents) in a base class?

I am looking for something like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "A::Foo" << endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "B::Foo" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public A, public B {
public:
    /*virtual void A::foo() {
        cout << "C::Foo" << endl;
    }*/ 
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.A::foo(); // want to get C::Foo here
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just call `c.foo()`? Is there an application behind you are trying to solve or just curiosity?

Comment: What is the point of inheriting from `A` and `B` if you want `C` to have its own `foo` ?

Comment: @Anedar, it is just curiosity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do this. If you want to avoid access to `class A;` via `class C;` explicit scope resolution make `A` private:

```
class C : private A, public B {
       // ^^^^^^^
public:
};
```

If you want to prefer the implementation of `A` you can specify what you want to use explicitly:

```
class C : public A, public B {
public:
    using A::foo();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It was not a question about a way to avoid access to a method in class A, I was just curious about the possibility of such overriding.